# Can a Lawyer represent a client in a business deal where he knows that his client is being screwed over?

Tags: contract-law, professional-ethics

Two people are partnering to purchase a business deal. A lawyer is representing Partner A. The lawyer knows that Partner A is being screwed over by Partner B, i.e. Partner B has no money to contribute, etc. Is the lawyer ethically allowed to represent Partner A?

Comment: Does he represent A or the partnership? Is there any reason the attorney can’t tell  A what he knows or suspects about B?

Comment: He represents Partner A. What's the law if he can't tell Partner A and what's the law even if he tells Partner A but the Partner doesn't seem to understand the situation?

Comment: I assume A is a competent adult who can make their own business decisions based on knowing all the facts. Of course the attorney might decide to break off their representation of A. If they are not in court an attorney can decline an engagement.

Comment: What hypothetical would prevent telling A?

Comment: The hypothetical reason would be loss of income from the representation.

Comment: What if the lawyer tells his client in a general way that Partner B might be trying to screw him over, but he doesn't explain every reason why he thinks so?

Comment: @James that's exactly would be **why** A should retain a lawyer. Your lawyer is there as a massive sanity-check and legal-check so you **don't** get screwed over.

Comment: @James The lawyer has a fiduciary duty to client A. To hide information from your client out of self-interest is a breach of duty and possibly even fraud.

Answer (score 4):

[british-columbia](/questions/tagged/british-columbia)

The lawyer must give "[an open and undisguised opinion of the merits and probable results of the client’s cause](https://www.lawsociety.bc.ca/support-and-resources-for-lawyers/act-rules-and-code/code-of-professional-conduct-for-british-columbia/chapter-3-%E2%80%93-relationship-to-clients/#3.7-7)."

"[When advising a client, a lawyer must be honest and candid and must inform the client of all information known to the lawyer that may affect the interests of the client in the matter](https://www.lawsociety.bc.ca/support-and-resources-for-lawyers/act-rules-and-code/code-of-professional-conduct-for-british-columbia/chapter-3-%E2%80%93-relationship-to-clients/#3.2-2)."

As long as the lawyer is satisfied that "[the client has the ability to understand the information relative to the decision that has to be made and is able to appreciate the reasonably foreseeable consequences of the decision or lack of decision](https://www.lawsociety.bc.ca/support-and-resources-for-lawyers/act-rules-and-code/code-of-professional-conduct-for-british-columbia/chapter-3-%E2%80%93-relationship-to-clients/#3.2-9)," the lawyer can take instructions from that client.

The lawyer would only be *required* to withdraw if the client [persists in instructing the lawyer to act contrary to professional ethics](https://www.lawsociety.bc.ca/support-and-resources-for-lawyers/act-rules-and-code/code-of-professional-conduct-for-british-columbia/chapter-3-%E2%80%93-relationship-to-clients/#3.7-7).

Comment: Benn there and done that, and this is exactly what an ethical lawyer does in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

### there's only few rules against representation

#### What means representing a client?

The lawyer is retained to represent **only the interests Partner A**. His obligation is **to do that to the best of his capacity.** That's exactly what he is paid for.

If he notices that Partner B tries to screw Partner A over, he should tell his client, Partner A, about this based on ethical reasons, and suggest a way to deal with that, and also propose solutions.

When Partner B conducts illegal or at least very shady business in the transaction, Parter A's lawyer is obligated to do the best to protect the interest of his client, partner A, and thus shield Partner A by the necessary steps. For example, the lawyer could make sure to include a passus that makes it possible to either exclude Partner B for nonpayment ("If B doesn't pay his share until X, all his rights in the transaction are extinguished") or to make the deal contingent on Partner B's payment ("A only agrees to the transaction on the condition that B has paid his share by X"). Partner A of course has to be informed of this by his lawyer, but **unless the lawyer is specifically instructed by his client not to take such steps, he has to protect his client's interests.**

#### What does ending representation mean?

The moment he drops representation, the Lawyer is no longer obligated to do anything in the pending matter. There are many reasons a lawyer can end his representation of A, but most of them are about what transpires between A and his lawyer.

#### What prevents representation by a lawyer?

The most common reason that would bar a lawyer from representing A is, if B had retained the very lawyer for the same or a very related matter, posing a conflict of interest. For example, if B had retained the lawyer last year for a similar deal, and knowledge of that deal's happenings would unduly influence this new deal, then the lawyer is barred to represent A.

> What's the law if he can't tell Partner A ...

This idea is absolute idiocy. The ethical rules are worded in such a way that it is the lawyer's duty that he **has** to tell his client.

> what's the law even if he tells Partner A but the Partner doesn't seem to understand the situation

The lawyer has to do his best to protect the interest of the client, as long as he represents his client. If instructed by Partner A to still go through with the deal in the way that it damages Partner A, the lawyer can either drop the representation or go through with it.